# Where is WDF template after installing wdk?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, wdf

visual studio community 2017 + wdk 10.0.15063.0 + sdk 10.0.15063.137

I installed vs2017 first,and then,the wdk.
However I cound't find the WDF template when I try to create a KMDF.

Appreciate for any help.

Comment: try the [WDK for the Fall Creators Update (current Insider Builds), here the WDK supports VS2017](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewWDK) "The WDK now supports Visual Studio 2017.  All editions are supported."

Comment: now you can get the 1709 WDK which now supports VS2017

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [WDK Build 15063 for Windows 10 v1703 only supports Visual Studio 2015](https://www.osr.com/blog/2017/03/07/visual-studio-2017-released-driver-devs-must-stay-vs-2015/). So for driver development you have to stay on the older VS2015 until a compatible version is available to be used in VS2017.

Starting with [WDK Build 16299 for Windows 10 v1709](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit) VS2017 is now the only supported option. So if you want to use only VS2017, install the WDK Build 16299/Win10 v1709.

[image]

If you still have issues, try to install the matching [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) (same Build number). This [fixed the issue for an user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49226147/1466046).

Comment: It's important you have to install WDK after the Visual Studio. Otherwise, you won't have WDF templates available. If you installed WDK first, try going to add/remove programs, select the WDK and choose repair. For the current latest WDK (10.0.17763.1), VS 2017 and Windows SDK 10.0.17763.132 templates are there if WDK installed after VS.

Comment: @Polyakoff in WDK folder there is an VSIX (Windows Kits\10\VSIX) which installs the templates