# Visual Studio WDK integration Issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, wdk

Recently I installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise along with WDK 10 for 1709 My workloads contained C++ workload. . My machine is a Windows 8.1 Pro with net framework 4.6.1. After installing the WDK I expected the templates to come in the Legacy section of Visual C++ but no legacy option is present in it.  I don't understand what is the problem. Please help me. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue. It was due to a missing windows 10  SDK. Reinstallating the WDK with appropriate SDK solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Developing drivers to windows is quite interesting one will be exposed to advanced Operating System Concepts. The set up for the environment will be IDE

1. IDE - Visual Studio (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16)
2. Compilers (WDK)
3. Debugger (WDK)

WDK contains both(https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2085767). Latest Visual Studio(VS2019) will come along with the latest WDK(10, 1903 as of now).

Sometimes plugins might not work properly i.e integration issues between Visual Studio and WDk.

- By going to the location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Vsix\VS2019" and run VSIX installer.
- Now in a new project, driver related templates are available.