# WDK Templates won't show up in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, driver, wdk

I started to play with Driver development again and I am using Visual studio Enterprise 2017.

I have something that actually gives me a headache as to now start asking why I install WDK and it does not show up in visual studio 2017. This, as far as I am concerned, has not been resolved.

Please anyone with an idea why this is impossible? I mean why WDK templates won't show in Visual studio 2017?

Comment: for VS2017 you need at least [WDK Build 16299/Windows 10 V1709](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43703309/1466046).

Comment: any update on your question?