# Windows Developement Kit on visual studio 2015 community do not work

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, wdk

I tryed to install Windows Development Kit on Visual Studio Community 2015, but it do not install correctly the software. 
Afther setup i don't find "driver" between visual studio's menu.
I tried to reinstall many times, also using control panel, without success...
Visual Studio 2017, instead, work correctly: there is the "driver" menu  and there is "driver windows kit" between the extensions and updates.
I have:
Windows 10 Pro, Version 1809.
I downloaded the appropriates WDK and SDK version from microsoft site.

Comment: I tryed to install Windows Driver Kit (WDK)...

Comment: for VS2015 you have to use the [15063/1703 WDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43703309/1466046), all later version require VS2017/2019

Comment: Great
I did the indicated setup (SDK and WDK)
now it works correctly
thank you so much

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads

Comment: Hi, it seems this issue is now resolved, please consider [adding the workaround as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help any member with similar issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Great I did the indicated setup (Windows 10, version 1703, SDK and WDK) now VS 2015 it works correctly, thank you so much.

Looking:
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads